# Change A Property For Every Dynamic Object In A Variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object

I am storing JSON objects with a name and `token` value

> Example Object in **tokenHandler.json**

```
{
   "A Random Name":{
      "token": 0
   }
}
```

My Goal Is to have a function add + 1 to `token` for every object in the JSON File every 5 seconds

```
function addToken() {
  const fs = require("fs");
  const tokenHander = require("tokenHandler.json");

  // My question is on this line of code
  tokenHandler.token = tokenHandler.token + 1;

  fs.writeFile("tokenHandler.json", JSON.stringify(tokenHandler), (error) => {
    if (error) return console.log(error);
  });

  return console.log("Added Token!");
}

setInterval(addToken, 5000);
```

What im having trouble with is accessing every object inside **tokenHandler**. With the current line; a 2nd `"token"` property is added into the object instead of incrementing the original. I want to have a way to access and change every `token` property of every object present in the json file regardless of the name of the object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Object.values` method to accomplish this. `Object.values()` will return an array of the values of object, which can then be chained using `forEach` to increase the value of token

```
function addToken() {

        const fs = require('fs')
        const tokenHander = require('tokenHandler.json')


        Object.values(tokenHander).forEach(item => item.token++)


        fs.writeFile('tokenHandler.json', JSON.stringify(tokenHandler), (error) => {

            if (error) return console.log(error)

        })

        return console.log('Added Token!')

    }

setInterval(addToken, 5000)
```